# Applying Oracle PL/SQL via JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, sqlplus

Is it possible to create/replace PL/SQL via the Oracle JDBC driver, i.e not via SQLPLus* ?

**Update 1:** Driver: ojdbc14 (JDBC)

**Update 2:** Change is being applied to oracle via Ant `<SQL>` task, which is passed a sql script file.

In this instance using SQLPlus in the Ant script is not possible (long story).

Comment: What driver are you talking about?  JDBC?  ODBC?  ODP.Net?  It is almost certainly possible.  But we'll need more information in order to provide any specifics.

Comment: Currently using ojdbc14, but flexible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the standard Ant sql task will do this.  These options are working for me:

```
sql driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
       delimiter="/"
       delimitertype="row"
       keepformat="yes"
       caching="true"
       escapeprocessing="no"
```

One thing I've found is that the processing is sensitive to the last line with the delimiter - if you have any whitespace after the "/" the execution will fail.